# K3S: CreateContainerError

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I got this error messages in my pod, using this command:

```
kubectl create deploy fastapi-helloworld --image=juanb3r/fastapi-multi:latest
```

I don´t know why the container can't be created.

[image]

Comment: please, don't use images but paste the output. what does kubectl get events tell you? it should give you more information about why the container cannot be created

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to install this:

```
zypper install apparmor-parser
```

on my vagrant